# Press twice for before function starts Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

sorry if the title is a bit sloppy or confusing, I'll try to explain it a bit more detailed.

I have a function in my app which allows users to only use it 10 times a day. The code below handles the counting per day which is actually working good except that the user always have to press twice on a new loop before it's getting called.

I think it has something to do with the `fabs` function, or what could be the reason the user has to press twice on a new loop?

```
-(void)dailyCount:(id)sender{
    NSString *kFirstLaunchDateKey = @"tenPerDay";
    NSDate *firstLaunchDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];
    NSInteger count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"perDay"];

    if (!firstLaunchDate) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count+1 forKey:@"perDay"];

        return;
    }

    NSTimeInterval diff = fabs([firstLaunchDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    if (diff > 60 * 60 * 24 * 1) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"tenPerDay"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"perDay"];
    }else{
        if (count % 11 == 0) {
            [UIAlertView showWithTitle:@"Daily Limit Exceeded"
                               message:@"Sorry, you can use this option only 10 times per day."
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil
                              tapBlock:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                                  if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

                                  }
                              }];
        }else {
            // do something here... (Have to press twice on a new loop before it's getting called)

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count+1 forKey:@"perDay"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because of your initial conditional that if there isn't a firstLaunchDate, it will create a new one but return without doing anything? Then when you press it again it will actually start to do something.

Comment: Any reason you're doing `count % 11 == 0` instead of just checking if `count > 10`? Also, why remove the object being stored in `perDay` instead of just setting it to 0?

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out, got it fixed, will post the answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)dailyCount:(id)sender{

    NSString *kFirstLaunchDateKey = @"tenPerDay";
    NSDate *firstLaunchDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];

    if (!firstLaunchDate) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"perDay"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self counterNew];

        return;
    }

    NSTimeInterval diff = fabs([firstLaunchDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    if (diff > 60 * 60 * 24 * 1) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"tenPerDay"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"perDay"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [self counterNew];

    }else{


        [self counterNew];

    }
}

-(void)counterNew{

    NSInteger count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"perDay"];

    if (count > 10) {

        [UIAlertView showWithTitle:@"Daily Limit Exceeded"
                           message:@"Sorry, you can use this option only 10 times per day."
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil
                          tapBlock:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                              if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

                              }
                          }];

    }else {


        //Do something here...

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count+1 forKey:@"perDay"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. Explain what the issue was and how the answer fixes it.

Comment: Like @Yarneo said, the method if(firstlaunchdate) will be called the first time and it was only setting the NSUSERDefault, so I split the function to do the counting in another void and called it in if(firstlaunchdate) as well. Really surprised I didn't saw that one though.